# spring application-security configuration bean scan

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-annotations, spring-bean

In my project, I needed a custom userDetailsService, So I declaire it like this in certain package:

```
@Service
@Ihm(name = "userDetailsService")// ignore Ihm, it's just a custom annotation, which works fine
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
```

And in my application-security.xml file, I added component-scan,

```
<context:component-scan base-package="path(including the userDetailsService for sure)" />

<context:annotation-config />
```

which didn't help me find my annotated bean, I got bean no defined exception.

The only way worked in my case is :
1.remove the service annotation
2.create the bean in the application-security.xml with beans:bean,id,class.
this works fine.

What's more funny is this, when I kept both the component-scan, and the annotation, I got an ID duplicated(more than one bean, ask to specify the ID) error.

```
 More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id reference in <remember-me/> <openid-login/> or <x509 /> elements.
```

So this means the `@Service` did create the bean, but y won't the security.xml find it?

Comment: Post the stack trace and additional configuration. Also when doing a component-scan the bean name would be `userDetailsServiceImpl`. Also `<context:annotation-config />` is implied by the use of `<context:component-scan />` so you probably want to remove that.

Comment: thanks, u r right, the bean's name is really userDetailsServiceImpl... could you tell me y? if the name's so, the name in Service works only for autowire of inject stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security is auto wiring beans on bean names, for the `UserDetailsService` that is `userDetailsService`.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
```

The code above (like your code) will lead to a bean of the type `UserDetailsService` however the name is `userDetailsServiceImpl` and not `userDetailsService` and hence your bean is never used by Spring Security nor detected by it. (See Spring [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-name-generator) for naming conventions_

To fix this either change the spring security configuration and [put in a reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-auth-providers) to your `userDetailsServiceImpl` bean

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsServiceImpl'/>
</authentication-manager>
```

or change the name of your bean by providing the name in the `@Service` annotation.

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
```

Either way will work.

**Links**

1. [Using other authentication providers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-auth-providers)
2. [Naming autodetected components](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-name-generator)